# un-deleting file after running "git reset" after running "git rm"

Tags: git, git-reset, git-rm

I accidentally ran `git rm file`

to undo that I ran `git reset HEAD` which didn't restore the file, so then I ran `git reset HEAD~1` which didn't seem to restore the file either (this should be easy...)

Now I see this:

```
Unstaged changes after reset:
M       test/.suman/logs/runner-debug.log
M       test/.suman/logs/test-debug.log
M       test/.suman/logs/test-output.log
M       test/.suman/logs/tests/test.test-src.alphabet.test.js.log
M       test/.suman/logs/tests/test.test-src.four.test.js.log
M       test/.suman/logs/tests/test.test-src.one.test.js.log
M       test/.suman/logs/tests/test.test-src.three.test.js.log
M       test/.suman/logs/tests/test.test-src.two.test.js.log
M       test/example.js
D       test/test-src/one.test.js
D       test/test-src/test-sort.js
M       test/test-src/z.test.js
```

what I am trying to do is restore

```
 D       test/test-src/one.test.js
```

how can I do that?

Comment: Have you tried to checkout that file?

Answer (score 2):

You were correct in running `git reset HEAD` first. This un-marked the file from deletion, after which it counts as a *change in the working directory*.

It is always helpful to run `git status`:

```
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
```

To restore the file, i.e. to discard the change of the content of the file being deleted:

```
$ git checkout -- test/test-src/one.test.js
```

Comment: hmmm...the checkout command you mention doesn't seem to work, the file is marked for deletion it does not appear to be in the index, a.k.a. I cannot use tab completion to find it

Comment: ok, it did seem to work, it just wasn't available for tab completion, for good reason

Answer (score 1):

[mkrieger1's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41644609/1256452) is correct (and upvoted), but you have a Situation now, so more is required—probably, `git reset @{1}`—first.  Here's the explanation.

When you ran `git rm path`, Git removed the given *`path`* from both the *index* (the next commit you're building now) and the *work-tree*.

When you subsequently ran `git reset HEAD`, Git made two changes, the first one of which was a no-op.  But then you ran a *second* `git reset` that also made two changes, and this time the first change was *not* a no-op.

#### What `git reset` does by default

- Whatever the current branch is, its commit is changed to the `HEAD` commit.  That is, if you're on branch `master`, Git resolves `HEAD` to some commit ID by reading `master`, then writes the commit ID it just produced into `master`.  Obviously, reading the ID, then writing it back unchanged, leaves it unchanged.  So this is kind of dumb, but is done because if you said `git reset HEAD~1` for instance, Git would convert `HEAD~1` to a commit ID, then write *that* commit ID into `master`—which is what it did for your *second* command.

  Once the current branch is adjusted, `HEAD` now resolves to the new commit ID.  So for your first `reset` command, `HEAD` did not change at all, and for your second one, `HEAD` stepped back one commit.
- Then, since you let `git reset` do a `--mixed` (default) reset, Git copies all the files from the adjusted `HEAD` into the index.

This second step is part of what you wanted, when you were undoing your `git rm`.  Your `git rm` removed the file from the index *and* from the work-tree.  Your `git reset HEAD` put the file back into the index, first "changing" `HEAD` to itself in the process.  But the file is still missing from your work-tree—and then you did the second `git reset`, which made things bad,

#### Recovering *most* of the way

Here's a crude text drawing of what you had before the two `git reset`s, in terms of the commit graph, all assuming you're on branch `master`:

```
...--A--B--C   <-- master
```

The first `git reset` moved `master` to point to commit `C`.  It already pointed to `C` so that's no change.  But, the *second* `git reset` moved `master` to point to commit `B`, leaving `C` dangling:

```
...--A--B    <-- master
         \
          C
```

To get `C` back, if you knew its commit ID, you would run:

```
git reset <commit-id>
```

This would tell Git to point the current branch (`master`) to commit `C` again:

```
...--A--B
         \
          C   <-- master
```

The tricky part is: where can you find the ID of commit `C`?  The answer is to use the *reflogs*.  There's one reflog for `HEAD`, and one reflog for each branch.  The one for `HEAD` gets a new entry every time you do something that changes which commit `HEAD` points to, and the one for the branch gets a new entry every time you change which commit the branch-name points to.  Since `git reset` adjusts both, they'll be found in both reflogs, probably as `HEAD@{1}` and `@{1}`.  (If you have done some additional `reset`s you may need `@{2}` or higher.  Also, be sure your shell does not eat the braces—some do; if yours does, you may need to use, e.g., `"@{1}"`.)

Hence:

```
git reset @{1}
```

or perhaps some higher number, perhaps with some extra quotes.  This should get your branch pointed back to the correct commit, *and* fill in the index.  (Or, you can use the raw hash ID, if you have that.  Git takes either hash IDs, or anything that converts *to* a hash ID.  To see what hash ID something converts to, use `git rev-parse`.  Try `git rev-parse HEAD`, for instance, and `git rev-parse master`.)

#### Getting the rest of the way

Now that you have the branch pointed back to the correct commit—that is, now that you're back to:

```
...--A--B--C   <-- master
```

or similar—the `git reset`, doing a `--mixed` reset, still leaves the desired file stored in the *index*, but not in the *work-tree*.

There are several ways to get the file back, but the simplest is to copy it from the index to the work-tree:

```
git checkout -- path
```

You can also use this, even if you hadn't run *any* `git reset` commands at all:

```
git checkout HEAD -- path
```

The key difference is that *this* version says: copy the given *`path`* from the `HEAD` commit into the index, then copy the same *`path`* from the index to the work-tree.

Comment: ok, I run git reset @{1} *after* checkout of the file marked for deletion?

Comment: Well, that will get you the version from the *previous* commit. Do it that way *if* that's what you want. Remember, each file has three versions: "what's in HEAD" (or other specified commit), "what's in the index", and "what's in the work-tree".